# Normalizing database MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

**Table values:**

[image]

**Tabel Desc:**

[image]

Is it normalized to 1NF, 2NF, 3NF? To the best of my knowledge and if i understand Normalization it cannot be divided again. Am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

We can still normalize the above structure as follows

`udegid, userid, designationid,designatedon,revokedon,status`

Where udegid is the guid for this table.

Similarly for the department we can have as 
`udeptid, userid, deptid, effectivefrom, effectiveto,status`

This approach enables you to track the history of the employee designation and dept throughout the lifetime of the employee.

HTH

Comment: Which NF does it violate?

Comment: every non-prime attribute of the table is dependent on the whole of every candidate key... Redundancy in nonprime attributes if you were to track the Dept / desig history

Comment: Can you give one example?

Comment: `select dept from table where userid='a'` this selects only dept

Comment: How can we handle the employees department / designation historical data without duplication of employee ID, it becomes redundant. Like I may begin my career as engineer, after couple of years, I graduate to sr.engineer and so on... HTH

Comment: Can you please start a chat. i do not know the link

Comment: What if the HR wants to get the engineers that have worked in a contoso project in the last five years and have switched departments now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74041/discussion-between-harikrishnan-n0077-and-saravanan).

Comment: i am in the chat window, can you make it quick

Comment: i have to leave in 5 minutes, if you can make it up, fine